# Is there a Visual Studio "go to file in selection" hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, resharper

I have some code that looks like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyComponent/MyPartial.vbhtml")
```

The same way I can put the cursor over methods and press F12 to go to the method's definition, I'd like to be able to put my cursor over the `"~/Views/Shared/MyComponent/MyPartial.vbhtml"` string and press some hotkey combination to navigate to that file.

Is there such hotkey in visual studio?

Vim and Resharper shortcuts accepted

[Edit]
Just to add context to one of the scenarios I encountered, I have a folder structure that goes something like this:

```
.
├─ _Views
|  ├── _Shared
|  |   └── SomePartial.vbhtml
|  └── _SomeComponent
|      └── Index.vbhtml
```

When I'm in `Index.vbhtml` I can use `@Html.Partial("SomePartial.vbhtml")` because asp.net mvc has a convention that if a file can't be found in the current directory it will search in the "Shared" directory.

Comment: in vim it is `gf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with Resharper's [go to file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File.html) shortcut, contrary to the documentation mine was unbound and I had to set it to ctrl+shift+t before I could use it.

The difference to VsVim's gf is that it searches the whole visual studio solution rather than the current directory and accepts the "~" character in the path when searching so I can type something like `vi" ctrl+shift+t`.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way is `gf`, as mentioned by [@Doktor OSwaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5276188/doktor-oswaldo). Note that this also works in visual mode!

However, there are other interesting options found with `:h gf`, including:

- `<Ctrl-W><Ctrl-F>` to open in a split buffer.
- If you want any text under the cursor to be opened as a new file when you enter `gf`, you can create the following mapping: `:map gf :e <cfile><CR>`
- If a number follows the name of the file under the cursor (like `eval.c:10` or `eval.c 40`), typing `gF` will position you at that line number.

Comment: This worked for me in some cases, but sometimes a partial view file may not be in the same directory as the place where it's referenced, in which case I get a message like "Can't find file for /Views/Shared/MyComponent/MyPartial.vbhtml"

Comment: I tried with relative and absolute paths and it works for me. Could you give a concrete example and the value you get with `:set path`?

Comment: :set path gives me ".,,". I added my folder structure in the question but in short, vim doesn't know of MVC's conventions so it only looks for the file in the current directory and misses the "Shared" directory.

Comment: Can you try setting it like so → `:set path=$PWD/**`. This should add anything relative to your current path recursively. For this to work, you would need to open at the root level of your project. Hopefully you are happy with your current solution!

Comment: @SébastienLavoie `E518: Unknown option: path`